# long chain of eloquent relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have the following models and relationships:

1. A **User** who posted the **Reply**
2. A **Reply** that belongs to a **Thread**
3. A **Thread** that belongs to a **Category**

The most recently active thread is defined by the thread that has the most recent reply posted by a user.

I have the following views.

1. A view that displays all the category titles and i want next to each category title to display the most recently active thread and the name of the user who posted that last reply on that thread.
2. A view that displays the list of threads and next to each thread title i want to display the name of the user who posted the last reply.

One solution would be

The Category Model :

```
Class Category Extends Model {

public function recentlyActiveThread(){

return $this->hasOne(Thread::class)->latest('updated_at');
 }
}
```

The Thread Model

```
Class Thread Extends Model {

public function recentReply(){

 return $this->hasOne(Reply::class)->latest('updated_at');
 }
}
```

The Reply Model

```
Class Reply Extends Model {

public function poster(){

    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
 }
}
```

Then in the view i can do.

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
<p> $category->recentlyActiveThread->title </p> 
<p>  $category->recentlyActiveThread->reply->poster </p>
@endforeach
```

I was wondering if there is a better way to approach this because it seems a little messy to me that i have to access so many different models in order to get the user who posted that reply.

In addition,  i give the responsibility to Category to know which one was the most recently active thread, which i don't know if that is ok.